# how to inherit and customise a class

Tags: less

I want to inherit a parent and add few classes in the middle. Like

```
.parent {
    li {
      a {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }  

 .child {
   li {
   a, button {
     color: red;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: It would be better if you show your expected CSS output also.

Answer (score 0):

In LESS you can extend mixins, but at present (LESS 1.5) it requires just a class definition, so this:

```
.parent {
  li {
    a {
        color: red;
      }
     }
   }

.child {
  &:extend(.parent);
  li {
   a, button {
     color: red;
     }
   }
 }
```